# What does "exploded configuration" in axis2 means?

Tags: configuration, weblogic, websphere, apache-axis

I'm reading this Application Server Specific Configuration Guide, http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html, for Axis2. What does "exploded configuration" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it just refers to exploded vs .war type deployment. For an example tomcat automatically explode (unpack) your war file once you deploy it. AFAIU this "exploded configuration" jargon has appeared due to option in Jboss appserver. [1]

AFAIR there is no specific configuration called exploded conf when it comes to axis2 (i'm talking about things such as axis2.xml/etc)

[1] http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExplodedDeployment

HTH

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! I'm getting confused with the "exploded configuration" because I can't seem to find such configuration in WebSphere so I'm also thinking that it just refers to an exploded war file. Is there any significance if a war file is exploded or not?